# Where does the token.json file come from, in the google drive api QuickStart for python?

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
```

I found this in google official page and there is file token.json and I want to know how to get it. I have watched many many videos but they showing that they make a key and then downloaded but i don't have that option to keys

Comment: Welcome to stack.   This is your second question and I have had to tweak the tags on both of them.   Adding tags will help you get answers on your questions.   Also if you are following a tutorial you should add a link to it in your question to help other users.

Answer (score 0):

Im going to take a while guess and say you are following the [python quick start for google drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python).   Which isn't so wild since I gave you the link to it in your last question.

Lets have a closer look at the code shall we.  The first thing the code does is check if `token.json` exists if it does not then it will request authorization of the user.

If the user grants authorization then it saves it in `token.json`

```
 # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())
```

## full code.

```
if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())
```

## answer

So to answer your question `token.json` is created by your code and contains the consent granted by the user.   May i suggest reading though the code rather than just copying the QuickStart.  There are comments that tell you what its doing.